# How to re-use item descriptions in Roxygen documentation?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen, rd

I am documenting many data frames in an R package, either because they are returned by a function or they are included as data. Oftentimes, the same column/item needs to be described for many data frames. **How can I avoid copy/pasting the same item description multiple times?**

For example, imagine I am documenting the following data frames in `R/data.R`:

```r
#' @name OBJ_1
#' @title Object 1
#' @format A data frame with 401 rows and 6 variables:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{character, a very carefully defined description}
#'   \item{\code{col1}}{double, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col2}}{integer, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col3}}{character, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col4}}{integer, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col5}}{character, blah}
#'}   
"OBJ_1"

#' @name OBJ_2
#' @title Object 2
#' @format A data frame with 333 rows and 5 variables:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{character, a very carefully defined description}
#'   \item{\code{col6}}{double, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col7}}{integer, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col8}}{character, blah}
#'   \item{\code{col9}}{integer, blah}
#'}   
"OBJ_2"
```

And similarly I want to document a data frame returned by a function:

```r
#' Some function 
#'
#' @return data frame with one row per feature:
#' \describe{
#'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{character, a very carefully defined description}
#'   \item{\code{colx}}{blah}
#'   \item{\code{coly}}{blah}
#' }
#' 
#' @export
#' 
myFunction = function(){
  # do stuff
  return(df)
}
```

In all three cases, `feature_ID` is defined the same way. Is there any way to define `feature_ID` somewhere **once** and use an expression in Roxygen that is evaluated to insert the desired definition in the .Rd docs?

`@eval` is a nice way to do this for repeated `@param`s, but `@eval` **does not work** inside another Roxygen tag like `@format` or `@describe`.

I also tried the [dynamic R code](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html#dynamic-r-code) solution, but this:

```r
feature_ID = function(){
  "character, a very carefully defined description"
}
...
#'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{`r feature_ID()`}
```

was evaluated to this in the corresponding .Rd:

```r
\item{\code{feature_ID}character, a very carefully defined description)`}
```

instead of:

```r
\item{\code{feature_ID}{character, a very carefully defined description}
```

...which seems like a bug more than any intended behavior...

From [this](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd.html#roxygen-templates), it sounds like `@templateVar name value` is promising, but I can't find any documentation about how to actually implement this.

I'd appreciate any help! Lots of copy/paste feels like a sin and would be horribly inefficient if/when we end up wanting to change the definition of a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the behavior described using the [dynamic R code](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html#dynamic-r-code) solution *was* a [bug](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2). I was using roxygen2 version 7.1.2. Updating to version 7.2.1 resolved the issue and gave me the solution I wanted.

Here's a complete example of how to dynamically insert text into Roxygen documentation upon rendering.

1. Define frequently used arguments/params/items in an R script, something like `R/define_params.R`. You don't need to add Roxygen tags, or if you do, add `@noRd` and do not include `@export` so that the function is not exported and a corresponding .Rd is not generated.

   ```r
   feature_ID = function(){
     "character, a very carefully defined description"
   }

   assay = function(){
     "character, another description I use a lot"
   }
   ```
2. Use [dynamic R code](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html#dynamic-r-code) to insert the string(s) in Roxygen documentation, including inside tags.

   ```r
   #' Some function 
   #'
   #' @return data frame with one row per feature:
   #' \describe{
   #'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{`r feature_ID()`}
   #'   \item{\code{colx}}{blah}
   #'   \item{\code{coly}}{blah}
   #' }
   #' 
   #' @export
   #' 
   myFunction = function(){
     # do stuff
     return(df)
   }
   ```

   ```r
   #' @name OBJ_1
   #' @title Object 1
   #' @format A data frame with 401 rows and 7 variables:
   #' \describe{
   #'   \item{\code{feature_ID}}{`r feature_ID()`}
   #'   \item{\code{assay}}{`r assay()`}
   #'   \item{\code{col1}}{double, blah}
   #'   \item{\code{col2}}{integer, blah}
   #'   \item{\code{col3}}{character, blah}
   #'   \item{\code{col4}}{integer, blah}
   #'   \item{\code{col5}}{character, blah}
   #'}   
   "OBJ_1"
   ```
3. Generate the docs using `roxygen2::roxygenise()`
4. If you look at the .Rd files, you will see that your R code was replaced with the strings defined in the corresponding functions, e.g.:

   ```
   ...
   \item{\code{feature}}{character, a very carefully defined description}
   \item{\code{assay}}{character, another description I use a lot}}
   ...
   ```